# Pandas - Extract all content based on certain keywords

Tags: pandas, string

I am trying to extract all the content from a Dataframe till a specific word appears. I am trying to extract the entire content till the following words appear:

**high, medium, low**

**Sample view of the text in the Dataframe:**

```
text
Ticket creation dropped in last 24 hours medium range for cust_a
Calls dropped in last 3 months high range for cust_x
```

**Expected output:**

```
text, new_text
Ticket creation dropped in last 24 hours medium range for cust_a, Ticket creation dropped in last 24 hours
Calls dropped in last 3 months high range for cust_x, Calls dropped in last 3 months
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `replace` and `regex`.

The idea will be to match any words from your list and then replace it and anything after it.

We use `.*` to match anything until the end of a string:

```
words = 'high, medium, low'
match_words = '|'.join(words.split(', '))
#'high|medium|low'

df['new_text'] = df['text'].str.replace(f"({match_words}).*",'',regex=True)


print(df['text_new'])

0    Ticket creation dropped in last 24 hours 
1              Calls dropped in last 3 months 
Name: text, dtype: object
```